# LocalAuthentication not recognizing FaceId is supported

Tags: android, react-native, touch-id, face-id, localauthentication

I'm using the `expo-local-authentication` module for biometrics authentication. I want to authenticate users with FaceId on my android device.

As per the [LocalAuthentication documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/local-authentication/#localauthenticationsupportedauthenticationtypesasync), I'm using the `LocalAuthentication.supportedAuthenticationTypesAsync()` method to determine what kinds of authentications are available on the device. On my devices it only returns `[1]`, which means my devices support `TouchID`. If it returns `[1,2]` that means the device has both types supported `(TouchId & Facial Recognition)`.

I'm wondering why it says my phone is only supporting TouchId even though I have a face unlock feature on my device.

My device Info:

Model Name: Vivo Y83,
Model Number: Vivo 182,
Android version: 8.1.0

Answer (score -1):

This module doesn't support Facial Recognition on android. It has nothing to do with your device model.

Comment: Is there any module that supports face unlock on android?